# Simple form validations using Angular 2

Tags: angular

Create  a simple form user name and password, create custom validation for the password field. (Password should have at least 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, 1 number, 1 special character, minimum of 8 characters, and maximum of 16 characters)

How to do that with above validations 
Please help me in this

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have asked for angular 2 not angular JS

Answer (score 0):

If IE10+ is enough for your purposes, then you might make use of the HTML input's pattern attribute as specified here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

In this case you'd specify a regex to validate your password, you can find several approaches on Stack Overflow!

If you wanna go for a custom validator as Angular offers it, check this tutorial: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/advanced-topics/basic-custom-validators/

It outlines approaches for both model driven and template driven forms, so no matter which way you chose for setting up your form, you'll find a solution there!